# Install iOS 4 docs on Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, documentation

I'm trying to find how to install iOS 4.x docs on Xcode 4.4.

Does anyone know the path to add it? Check and Install Now doesn't find the old versions as options.

[image: Preferences Download Manager]

Comment: Clicking the Check and Install Now button makes the iOS 4.3 documentation set available for me on Xcode 4.4 running 10.8. I didn't have the Check for and install automatically checkbox selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by an update to Xcode.